# How can I create a quick launcher in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, launcher

How can I set up quick launchers in Lubuntu?

I've installed Lubuntu 14.04. Now I see no way to set quick launchers, especially for programs not listed in the menu (which must be started from a terminal).

Comment: Look at this [How to create desktop shortcut or launcher on Linux](http://xmodulo.com/2013/11/create-desktop-shortcut-launcher-linux.html) (Create a Desktop Shortcut on LXDE Desktop) and this [How to customise the LXDE desktop using Lubuntu](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/11/how-to-customise-lxde-desktop-using.html)

Comment: Unfortunately neither of the hints helped, since t. e. my desktop won't offer "create new launcher" an right-click ...

Comment: ... finally I managed creating a starter manually, which was less diffucult than it first looked.

Comment: I'd like to switch to lubuntu, but the fact that even docking an icon on the taskbar is this level non-evident is a huge turndown.

Answer (score 31):

You can follow this to create a launcher on the Lubuntu desktop.

Run this command in a terminal:

```
lxshortcut -o ~/Desktop/myLauncher
```

Choose the path to the application or just run a command:

[image]

Select an icon if you want:

[image]

Comment: (lxshortcut:39921): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 21:43:45.777: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed ... editor runs but hitting OK doesn't seem to save nor change anything.  Lubuntu 20.04. blocked.

Comment: Under Lubuntu 20, this does in fact create a file named "myLauncher" inside your home ~/Desktop directory, but when double-clicking on it, it comes up inside the text editor, instead of launching.  Two pieces of magic: (1) RENAME the file to "mylauncher.desktop" extension; (2) the back half, the ".desktop", is quietly invisible in the visual file browser.  (Try cutting and pasting the file over itself to reveal this invisible ext.)  You may also have to add a "Terminal=true" line inside the file if you're launching a shell script.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `PCManFM` file manager:
first select file,
then choose in command panel `Edit` -> `Create Link...`
then choose destination folder
[link creation sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwyLB.png)

Answer (score 5):

I downloaded the package known as 'menulibre' through synaptic package manager. It helps to create a launcher in our application menu which can be added to panel if required.

menulibre can be installed using apt

```
sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

Comment: Does menulibre work with Lubuntu menu?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, if I need to add any things to my quick launch (Alt + F2), I added it to my path, usually the simplest way is just create a symlink to the /usr/bin

For example: I have my android studio which can be launch by

`./opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`

I will do the symlink:

`sudo ln -s /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh /usr/bin/android-studio`

Now, when you press `Alt + F2`, and type `android-studio`, you should find the program.

it should work the same if you put it into your path variable by modifying your `.bash_profile` file. But usually source the profile file doesn't get `Alt+F2` work immediately in this case for me, I need to logout or restart my computer for it to work.

Note: remember to make your file executable by `chmod a+x`

My system is Lubuntu 15.10.