# LXDE/Lubuntu sees Java .jar files as zip archives instead of java archives when Webupd8 Oracle Java 8 is used

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, java, lxde, minecraft

I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit installed on my computer, with the Lubuntu-desktop installed as well. I have OpenJDK 7, and I can execute `.jar` files fine in both desktops.

After installing Oracle Java 8 (oracle-java8-installer and oracle-java8-set-default packages from the [Webupd8 PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html)), Lubuntu/LXDE sees `.jar` files as zip archives and I can no longer execute `.jar` files in Lubuntu/LXDE in a GUI with either Oracle or OpenJDK Java (pcmanfm/desktop).

Ubuntu (Unity) picks up the change and executes `.jar` files with Oracle Java.

Is there any way I can execute `.jar` files on Lubuntu/LXDE with Oracle Java without having to use the terminal (eg `java -jar FTB_Launcher.jar`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to try a little shell scripting the first time, you can make this command a shortcut on your homepage.

This will be along the lines of this tutorial: [How can I create a quick launcher in Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466395/how-can-i-create-a-quick-launcher-in-lubuntu)

**Write a Simple Bash Script**

For this instance, the first think you'll want to do is write your script. In any text editor (Leafpad or nano are easy), type this file:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar /home/dave/Downloads/Minecraft.jar
```

(but then replace "/home/dave/Downloads/Minecraft.jar" with the absolute path to the .jar file you want to run.)

Once you've written that script, I would recommend you save that it in a folder in your home directory called "bin". In my example case, I have saved it as /home/dave/bin/Minecraft.sh

**Change Permissions of Your Script**

Next, you'll need to allow execution of that script. If you don't mind if other users can execute it, you can use:

```
chmod 755 ~/bin/Minecraft.sh
```

...Which gives you the right to read, write, and execute that file, and gives others the right to read & execute the file.

**Finally, time to make the desktop shortcut.**

Again in the terminal, type:

```
lxshortcut -o ~/Desktop/Minecraft
```

Replace Minecraft with the name you'd like it to have. This will create a desktop icon with that name and allow you to set it up.

Under Desktop Entry, next to "Command:" you will be able to browse to your script file (the .sh you made earlier) and give it a description or a new icon, if you want.

[image: Desktop Shortcut Settings for Minecraft]

Now, with a double-click of that shortcut, you should have Java opening that .jar

Note: Edited from original answer that relied on Nautilus.

Comment: Are you sure the screenshots show PCManFM? It looks like nautilus to me...

Comment: You are right - that is obviously Nautilus. Must have been asleep when posting this. I have a different suggestion that's totally different that works - will edit to list that way.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I can now launch Minecraft on Lubuntu easier! I use the .sh files in Unity and the lxshortcut generated files in Lubuntu