# App launcher on lubuntu

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, lxde

I just installed lubuntu on my dell inspiron

Just wondering if i can install the app launcher (on the left side of the screen in Ubuntu) without installing GNOME ?

Comment: What do you mean by `app launcher`?

Comment: Did you try [these solutions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/466395/how-can-i-create-a-quick-launcher-in-lubuntu)

Comment: Can you post an image of what you want exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't install just the Launcher from Ubuntu, you would need the whole desktop and it REQUIRES `gnome` as Unity is based on `gnome`

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I would just like to point out that using this kind of defeats the point of Lubuntu being as light as possible, as Unity the Ubuntu desktop, is very heavy on resources, but it is your choice, though using Xubuntu may be a better solution, or

A dock should meet your needs, I would recommend `plank`, previously `docky`, it is still maintained and can be moved to the left of your display.

Run this in a terminal to install `plank`,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/docky
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install plank
```

[image]

Sorry I could not find an image of it on the left on Lubuntu, but you can change the `alingement` in settings to move it..

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If this is the answer you were looking for please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and let others know this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this app launcher on the left?

[image]

If so, it is the Unity shell, and you can use it by installing the `unity` package (instead of installing the whole Ubuntu desktop.

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Bear in mind that this will pull **lots** of packages from the official Ubuntu desktop, including several components of GNOME (although not the whole GNOME environment), and may defeat the purpose of running LUbuntu, as a light environment.

Comment: Installing Unity will **not** pull GNOME. I agree with your answer, though, that it defeats the purpose of using Lubuntu. Just let the asker decide from the screenshots which one he/she actually wants and decide which answer they prefer.

Comment: The result of `apt-get install gnome` in my current install is:

    `0 packages upgraded, 220 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 127 MB of archives. After unpacking 614 MB will be used.`

But, fine. I'll add a mention to it to please you.

Comment: @markkirby done. Other than that, I can offer to delete the answer.

Comment: Solid edit, don't take this as me being hostile, I only care that this answers the question directly, this is a community run site after all, and is good content for the site. As it does now answer the question and I appreciate you taking the criticism constructively, many don't,  have a +1 instead :)

Comment: No need to delete, users will make suggestions on how to improve an answers all the time, we can seem a bit brash but the point is constructive criticism, not to be mean, we have been around longer and understand how things work, meeting the edit requests is a great way to earn some rep as you learn the ropes around here. :)